# Can my old desktop run Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, system, system-requirements

I'm ditching Windows 10 once and for all and I was wondering if my oldish desktop can rock and roll with Ubuntu 18.04!? The PC configuration is as follows: [Intel core i5-660,](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/43550/intel-core-i5-660-processor-4m-cache-3-33-ghz.html) 8GB RAM (DDR3), Nvidia GeForce GTX 650, SSD 120 GB. I read that Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Gnome 3 which is a resource hungry DE.

Comment: Of course it can run Ubuntu 18.04 happily. But, it also depends on what resource hungry things you are planning to use on top of it!

Comment: If GNOME is unmutual, you can change your desktop to KDE, XFCE, LXQt, and other lighter desktops. Try it, and see if you like GNOME first, though.

Comment: Your PC will run it easily, try it first though

Comment: FedonKadifeli, the resource hungry things I usually do is playing some steam games (Dota 2 and CS:GO), and video editing. I'm happy to read that my pc can run Ubuntu Gnome. Other desktop environments don't appeal to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it should be fine also ubuntu and many other distros have what is called a live cd/usb so you can boot from a live usb or dvd and test the os before you install it to make one follow the instructions from this ubuntu tutorials page

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your computer fit the System Requirements

> 2 GHz dual core processor
>   2 GiB RAM (system memory)
>   25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
>   VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
>   Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

You can see them here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements